# Distance between two locations in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can some one help me what went wrong on this code snippet ? My ultimate aim to find distance two locations using googles javascript API . I have used geocomplete jquery function for address autocomplete. On click of search nothing is happening.Im just a beginner please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Distance between Two Places</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
     <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAA7j_Q-rshuWkc8HyFI4V2HxQYPm-xtd00hTQOC0OXpAMO40FHAxT29dNBGfxqMPq5zwdeiDSHEPL89A" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

    var geocoder, location1, location2;

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    }

    function showLocation() {
        geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].address1.value, function (response) {
            if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
            {
                alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the first address");
            }
            else
            {
                location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].address2.value, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                    {
                        alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the second address");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                        calculateDistance();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function calculateDistance()
    {
        try
        {
            var glatlng1 = new GLatLng(location1.lat, location1.lon);
            var glatlng2 = new GLatLng(location2.lat, location2.lon);
            var miledistance = glatlng1.distanceFrom(glatlng2, 3959).toFixed(1);
            var kmdistance = (miledistance * 1.609344).toFixed(1);

            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<strong>Distance: </strong>' + miledistance + ' miles (or ' + kmdistance + ' kilometers)';
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            alert(error);
        }
    }



    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">

    <form action="#" onsubmit="showLocation(); return false;">
      <input id="geocomplete" type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Type in an address" size="90" />
        <input id="geocomplete1" type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Type in an address" size="90" />
     <input type="submit" name="find" value="Search" />
    </form>

   <p id="results"></p>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="logger.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function(){

        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete()
          .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
            $.log("Result: " + result.formatted_address);
          })
          .bind("geocode:error", function(event, status){
            $.log("ERROR: " + status);
          })
          .bind("geocode:multiple", function(event, results){
            $.log("Multiple: " + results.length + " results found");
          });

          $("#geocomplete1").geocomplete()
          .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
            $.log("Result: " + result.formatted_address);
          })
          .bind("geocode:error", function(event, status){
            $.log("ERROR: " + status);
          })
          .bind("geocode:multiple", function(event, results){
            $.log("Multiple: " + results.length + " results found");
          });

        $("#find").click(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
        });


        $("#examples a").click(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").val($(this).text()).trigger("geocode");
          return false;
        });

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using the deprecated (and turned off) [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference).  New code should be developed in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) (you are actually including both versions, they are not really compatible and should never be both included (unless you really knew  what you were doing).

Answer (score 9):

You could use [DistanceMatrixService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) of google map for calculating distance between two points.

The following functions calculates the

```
function calculateDistances() {
  origin = document.getElementById('source').value; //Get the source string
  destination = document.getElementById('dest').value; //Get the destination string
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService(); //initialize the distance service
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin], //set origin, you can specify multiple sources here
      destinations: [destination],//set destination, you can specify multiple destinations here
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING, //set the travelmode
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,//The unit system to use when displaying distance
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, calcDistance); // here calcDistance is the call back function
}
```

Code for callback function calcDistance

```
function calcDistance(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) { // check if there is valid result
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    deleteOverlays();

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;

      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

        alert ('Distance from '+origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
            + ': ' + results[j].distance.text ); // alert the result
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find a working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/amodAJuQ/1/)

Comment: This is fantastic. Works great!

Comment: if the edits haven't been updated, make sure you omit the line `deleteOverlays();`, or define it.  I also gave you a +1 because, otherwise, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

When you call `calculateDistance()`, give `location1` and `location2` as parameters

```
var earthRadius = 6371;

function calculateDistance(posA, posB) {
    var lat = posB.lat-posA.lat; // Difference of latitude
    var lon = posB.lon-posA.lon; // Difference of longitude

    var disLat = (lat*Math.PI*earthRadius)/180; // Vertical distance
    var disLon = (lon*Math.PI*earthRadius)/180; // Horizontal distance

    var ret = Math.pow(disLat, 2) + Math.pow(disLon, 2); 
    ret = Math.sqrt(ret); // Total distance (calculated by Pythagore: a^2 + b^2 = c^2)

    // Now you have the total distance in the variable ret
}
```

Comment: Just to mention, this calculates the distance in km.

Answer (score 2):

You could also simply use the function computeDistanceBetween() exposed as part of api v3. Docs available [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance).

The function takes two latlng's as parameters and returns the distance between the two in metres.

Comment: Is this source available anywhere to view?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the starting of your `JavaScript` :

```
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function(latlng) {
  var lat = [this.lat(), latlng.lat()]
  var lng = [this.lng(), latlng.lng()]
  var R = 6378137;
  var dLat = (lat[1]-lat[0]) * Math.PI / 180;
  var dLng = (lng[1]-lng[0]) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
  Math.cos(lat[0] * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat[1] * Math.PI / 180 ) *
  Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = R * c;
  return Math.round(d);
}
```

and then use the `function` like this:

```
var loc1 = new GLatLng(52.5773139, 1.3712427);
var loc2 = new GLatLng(52.4788314, 1.7577444);
var dist = loc2.distanceFrom(loc1);
alert(dist/1000);
```